# Does the inside of a solid object not interact with the outside environment? But how does quantum decoherence happen?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements, measurement-problem, quantum-measurements, decoherence

We have learned that quantum decoherence is caused by interaction with the environment.  However, inside our body, there is no interaction with photons or air molecules in the environment, so how does quantum decoherence occur? Does the inside of a solid object not interact with the outside environment? But how does quantum decoherence happen?

Comment: What do you need quantum decoherence for in the first place?

Comment: How does a quantum decoherence occur inside a solid object? Does the inside of an object interact with something, just like the outside interacts with air molecules and photons and everything else?

Comment: Quantum decoherence always happens, it's just a question on which timescale. If it's faster than what we are interested in, then it makes the system more classical, if it's slower, then the system keeps showing quantum mechanical properties. In a solid "the slowest" it can occur is probably through phonons (quantized lattice vibrations), i.e. roughly at the speed of sound in the material, even if we assume perfect shielding against electromagnetic radiation.

Answer (score 0):

The insides of objects are not as isolated from the surrounding environment as you think. For example, every cell in your body requires a constant supply of oxygen atoms in order to carry out the [cellular respiration process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_respiration) that provides it with energy. These oxygen atoms comes from the outside atmosphere via the lungs and the circulatory system. If this supply of oxygen is interrupted for more than a few minutes then you die.

Comment: Since humans breathe, the inside of the body also interacts with the environment, but how do other objects interact with the environment? So, how does the inside of an object, like a cube or a pillar of a building, interact with the environment?

Comment: @Nunes Atoms and molecules in the environment interact with atoms/molecules near the surface of the object, which in turn interact with atoms/molecules further inside the object and so on.

Comment: So, conversely, would it be quantum coherence if it was completely separated from the external environmental photons and air? Or do body's subatomic particles interact with each other in our bodies, resulting in quantum decoherence?